# Database.stateful not maintaining state

Tags: apex, batch

I'm trying to use Database.stateful interface in one of by batch to perform some action on list of AccountIDs and i want to keep track of the Accountids for whom action has already been performed in Execute method and in subsequent iteration want to skip those Accountids .

below is the code

```
public class Test_Batch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.AllowsCallouts,Database.Stateful{
    set<id> idsSet = new set<id>();
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){

    string sQuery = 'Select id, Phone, Contact__c, Account__c from Locations__c';
    return Database.getQueryLocator(sQuery);
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC,   List<Locations__c> lstlocations ){
        if(lstlocations != null && lstlocations .size()>0){
            for(Locations__c oloc : lstlocations ){
                if(!idsSet.contains(oloc .Account__c)){
                    idsSet.add(oloc .Account__c);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    }
}
```

But in every iteration the idsSet is getting reset, and if same AccountIds coming in different iteration of execute method then on same accountids the actions are being performed . I've tried using list & map the result is same . It's working fine and state being preserved if i use that set in Finish method but in execute method it's getting reset .

Comment: Please avoid adding tags which have nothing to do with what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But in every iteration the idsSet is getting reset, and if same AccountIds coming in different iteration of execute method then on same accountids the actions are being performed.

No, `idsSet` is not being reset. `Database.Stateful` does work as advertised. The problem with your code is whatever you've omitted from this question. The most likely problem is that you have an uncaught exception, which prevents `Database.Stateful` from serializing the results of the transaction. That, or you have some other problem in your code.

---

Don't use a query "string" whenever possible, but instead use an inline query.

```
return Database.getQueryLocator([
    Select id, Phone, Contact__c, Account__c from Locations__c
]);
```

---

```
    if(lstlocations != null && lstlocations .size()>0){
```

The `scope` parameter of `execute` will never be null, and will never be empty. You do not need to check these conditions. More generally speaking, iterating over an empty list is always acceptable, so no need to check that as an entry condition.

---

```
if(!idsSet.contains(oloc .Account__c)){
    idsSet.add(oloc .Account__c);
}
```

First, you don't need to check if the value is already in the set, except to say that you want to do something for accounts not yet processed, so the more efficient way to write this is:

```
if(!idsSet.add(oloc.Account__c)) {
  continue; // We already have this account Id
}
```

The add method returns true if the set was modified by adding the value, false otherwise.

---

If you want to perform actions for the accounts only once, why not query for the accounts instead?

```
public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
    return Database.getQueryLocator([
        SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Id In (SELECT Account__d FROM Locations__c)
    ]);
}
public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, Account[] scope) {
    Locations__c[] locations = [SELECT Account__c, Phone__c, Contact__c FROM Locations__c WHERE Account__c = :scope];
    // rest of logic //
}
```

Comment: Alternatively the OP could be erroneously thinking that the `idsSet` would be shared across all separate instances of the batch (not the start/execute*n/finish flow of a single batch)?

Comment: @PhilW That's an interesting thought. I guess we'll have to wait and see what they say.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox , This was a really good explanation . The logic i'm performing in the execute method is that . I'm querying for all location and 100s of location can have 1 account , so suppose out of these 100s location record , 50 comes in one iteration of execute batch , then we do some logic then sends an email to the contact of that account . but in next iteration if same account comes in then another mail was triggring to that accounts Contact, i tried to use database.stateful to track the state of accountids , but with no success . but it's working completely fine in Finish Method.

Comment: @Salesforcegeek Yes, it sounds like you want to query by account in the start method, then send the relevant information. You don't need to track the accounts that way.

Comment: @sfdcfox yup that would serve my purpose as well . But was generally confused with Why can't database.stateful preserve it's state in Execute method iterations but works like a charm in finish method .  With the same approach , may be best approaches as you mentioned is not followed but still that set should have the accountids of previous iterations of execute method right ? then should be able to mitigate same accountids in subsequent iteration of execute method , but it adds back same ids again to the set and performs the email logic again for those account .

Comment: @Salesforcegeek How do you know that it's not storing the values? Have you checked the debug logs? I have never observed the problem you're seeing, and I've been using Apex since it was a Developer Preview. You'd need to do some more debugging to figure out the core problem. I presume either it's a logic bug in your code, or maybe something obscure, like exceeding the serialization size limit (but the latter sounds wrong, as you claim that finish is working correctly).

Comment: @sfdcfox sure would do some debugging on it as well .I have used set so that it can store only unique values and used contains method as well to check if set has that Id or not , If not then add the id to the set and Perform logic on the contact of that set of ids . so in 1 iteration of execute method the AccountId gets added in to the set then in subsequent iterations that accountIds should not be added as it's should already be there from previous iteration of set but thats not happening and again the accountIds are being added and logic for that contact of AccountId is being performed again

Comment: @Salesforcegeek Right, a set is the correct method for checking unique values, but again, I suspect that it's something else wrong in your code. Try using the `if(!set.add(value))` that I suggested, see if that changes anything. Or, you might want to edit your question to include the full code. It may just be a logic bug in your code.

Comment: @sfdcfox sure will definitely give it a try . Thanks for all the explanations